# I need to users to enter a time in one format, convert it to another, perform a calculation, then bring it back again

Tags: java, android

I am building an app that will convert swimming times from yards to meters, and can't figure out some important stuff.

I need a user to enter a time as this: `minutes:seconds.hundredths`
But it has to come to me in milliseconds, so that I can perform the conversion.  After that I need to put it back into that format and display it to the user.

For example, if someone swam a 200 yard Freestyle in 1:52.43, I need to figure out how to multiply it by 1.11 and add 3.2 seconds, then display it to the user as their converted time for a 50 meter length pool.

Comment: Okay, so you need conversions to and from that format... which part is giving you problems?

Comment: I can't figure out a way to use a widget that will let them type or select the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.  For example, if someone swam a 200 Freestyle in 1:52.43, I need to figure out how to multiply it by 1.11 and add 3.2 seconds, then display it to the user as their converted time.

Answer (score 3):

If your date format is like "2011-05-31 23:59:59";

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        java.util.Date dateObj = null;
        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(pDate);
            millisecond = dateObj.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For more info for Date formatting refer 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for, I added an example of what needs to happen in the main question though.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html